# Два байта конвертировать в short

Tags: java

Есть число 1111 1111 0010 0000 (-224). Вручную ввожу первый байт и второй байт. Затем нужно в short положить эти байты и вывести его десятичное представление.
Пробовал, но изначальное число на выходе не получается. Вот код:

```
public class pair {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    byte b1;
    byte b2;
    System.out.println("Введите последовательность бит для первого байта");
    byte[] input = new byte[1];
    int fstByte = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    String fstByte1 = Integer.toString(fstByte);
    if (fstByte1.equals("11111111")){
        fstByte1 = "-1111111";
    }
    input[0] = Byte.parseByte(fstByte1, 2);
    b1 = input[0];
    System.out.println("Введите последовательность бит для второго байта");
    int scndByte = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    String scndByte1 = Integer.toString(scndByte);
    input[0] = Byte.parseByte(scndByte1, 2);
    b2 = input[0];
    String res = toDec(b1 ,b2);
    System.out.println(res);

}

public static String toDec (byte b1, byte b2){
    String result = null;
    byte[] arrByte = new byte[2];
    arrByte[0] = b1;
    arrByte[1] = b2;
    System.out.println("Число в шестнадцетиричном виде");
    for (byte b : arrByte){
        System.out.format("0x%x ", b);
    }
    System.out.println();
    short[] res = new short[arrByte.length/2];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(arrByte).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(res);
    result =  String.valueOf(res[0]);
    System.out.println();


    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: думаю, Вам нужно почитать о том, что такое [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все было гораздо прозаичнее. Надо было просто расширить short до int:) 
Если кому-то понадобится метод, который из двух байтов получает short и возвращает строковое представление int этого числа, то вот он:

```
static String toDecStrFromBytes (byte b1, byte b2){
    String result = null;
    byte[] arrByte = new byte[2];
    arrByte[0] = b1;
    arrByte[1] = b2;
    System.out.println("Число в шестнадцетиричном виде");
    for (byte b : arrByte){
        System.out.format("0x%01X ", b);
    }
    System.out.println();
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    bb.put(b1);
    bb.put(b2);
    short shortVal = bb.getShort(0);
    int x = (int) shortVal;
    return Integer.toString(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Автору(Да и всем желающим) в копилку:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestClass().converter("1111111100100000");
}

public Short converter(String byteLikeString) {
    StringBuilder sb = invert(byteLikeString);
    return (short) (byteLikeString.charAt(0) == '0' ? count(sb) : count(sb) * -1);
}

private StringBuilder invert(String base) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < base.length() - 1; i++) {
        sb.append(base.charAt(i) == '1' ? '0' : '1');
    }
    sb.append('1');
    return sb;
}

private Short count(StringBuilder sb) {
    short result = 0;
    char temp;
    for (int i = sb.length() - 1, x = 1; i >= 0; i--, x += x) {
        temp = sb.charAt(i);
        if (x > 128)
            x = 1;
        result += temp == '1' ? x : 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Преобразование [дополнительного кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0))